# Develop in HTML... without classes/ID

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

I've just found out the pseudo-classes utilisation (:nth-child etc...).

I have a question in my mind about this : The use of those pseudo-classes, which permit the suppression of the classes in the HTML code, is a benefit ? In relation with SEO, performance, W3C etc...

Here is an example (just a test, so no responsive and the image aren't loading, but we don't care) : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNjQEM

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Exercice Facultatif">
    <meta name="author" content="Nathan Cheval">
    <title>Exercice facultatif</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body> 

    <!-- START HEADER -->
    <header>
        <div>
            <img src="imgs/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Activités</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <!-- START CONTENT -->
    <div>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="imgs/mtp.png" alt="Lac de Montpellier">
                        <figcaption>
                            Lac de Montpellier
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Les lacs d’Occitanie</h1>
                    <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis consequat ex a erat feugiat suscipit. Aenean mattis dolor eget metus tempor, et semper tortor viverra. Curabitur rutrum ornare dolor a molestie.<br><br>
                     Fusce ut arcu vulputate, bibendum urna sed, mollis odio. Integer dictum justo nulla, non rutrum odio lacinia eget. Sed faucibus metus vel lacus ultrices condimentum. Pellentesque molestie laoreet imperdiet. <br><br>
                     Morbi cursus blandit est. Sed id varius purus. Pellentesque id tempor felis. Praesent orci nunc, imperdiet et mi eget, luctus lacinia erat.<br><br>
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Lire la suite...</a>
                </div>
            </article>
            <hr>
            <article>
                <div>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="imgs/mtp.png" alt="Lac de Montpellier">
                        <figcaption>
                            Lac de Gergovie
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Les lacs d’Auvergne</h1>
                    <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis consequat ex a erat feugiat suscipit. Aenean mattis dolor eget metus tempor, et semper tortor viverra. Curabitur rutrum ornare dolor a molestie.<br><br>
                     Fusce ut arcu vulputate, bibendum urna sed, mollis odio. Integer dictum justo nulla, non rutrum odio lacinia eget. Sed faucibus metus vel lacus ultrices condimentum. Pellentesque molestie laoreet imperdiet. <br><br>
                     Morbi cursus blandit est. Sed id varius purus. Pellentesque id tempor felis. Praesent orci nunc, imperdiet et mi eget, luctus lacinia erat.<br><br>
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Lire la suite...</a>
                </div>
            </article>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!-- START CONTENT -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help clarifying this subject

Comment: SEO: who knows, ask Google. Performance: measure it. W3C: what does that even mean? I would advise you to try to write a moderately complex website with moderately complex CSS using only `:nth-child` selectors and such… your CSS will be a complete mess!

Comment: Styling with `:nth-child` selectors at all time is totally a bad idea. In this way you can't group similar items in a class and styles them uniquely. As a result your css size will be increased dramatically.

Comment: Classes make your code more declarative. Find a class naming system that works and stick with it.

Comment: I don't see any advantages, in any area. You would give up on some really powerful features, without any positive side effect.

Answer (score 1):

The key use for classes is to identify certain parts of your site which repeat here and there and should always be styled the same. Say, a date widget attached to each blog post in a list. Or a social media widget placed here and there.

```
<div class="posted-date">
    <span class="month">Sep</span>
    <span class="day">16</span>
</div>
```

You need *something* to uniquely identify these "objects" (yes, thinking of them as self-contained objects is a good idea). If you use custom HTML tags in one way or another, that's a good identifier:

```
<posted-date><month>Sep</month><day>16</day></posted-date>
```

In this case you do not need classes, since the tag name is sufficiently self-identifying. If you want to stick to a certain DTD though and cannot/won't define your own tags, classes serve this role instead.

Further, in moderately complex HTML, using only `:nth-child` selectors and such, to some degree you'll always end up identifying elements by their *position* within the page:

```
header > nav ul li:nth-child(2) span { /* the date widget /* }
```

Well, what happens when you move an element around? Now you need to adjust your CSS too. Or if the same element is in various positions on your page and should receive the same style every time? You'll need to specify a lot of selectors, and, again, adjust the CSS every single time you place the item someplace new.

If you don't need classes because you can identify an element well enough just by its or its parent's tag name or such, or your selectors are otherwise already well enough defined and *won't easily break* if you move things around a bit, absolutely, no need to add superfluous classes. However, in general, tying styles to the *structure* of your HTML produces tight coupling, which is pretty much always a bad idea.

Writing maintainable CSS is something of an art. *You* need to find the right balance for your project. The more complex, the more refined strategies you need to develop to keep your HTML and CSS sane. Going overboard with classes on simple projects may not be worth it. Avoiding classes at all costs on complex projects and you'll eventually paint yourself into an unmaintainable corner.

Comment: "pretty much always a bad idea" Disagree, there are a number of situations where you *do* want to style elements in specific positions (even if they're not the first or last), but the general idea of tightly coupling your *entire* stylesheet to your HTML is definitely a no-no.

Comment: Even in that case I'd probably rather add an additional class to some parent element rather than writing a selector for a specific location. Obviously though, there's always going to be a mix of *location-based* and *identity-based* styling. You just want to keep your location-based selectors rare and as short as possible. `body > header > nav > ul > li > span` is mostly certainly way too specific and inflexible.

Comment: There is no point in having a class or id whose sole purpose is to mark an element's location.

Comment: Indeed, that's why it should be a descriptive modifier. What's different about element 1 from element 2 (or a parent thereof) that makes you want to apply a different style to it? Describe that as a class. `.primary`, `.secondary`, or something like that.

Comment: That's assuming there is a semantic difference between elements 1 and 2. If there is not, but the layout calls for 1 to be aesthetically different by virtue of being the first, that's when an additional class is unnecessary. I remember when people were complaining about IE6 not supporting :first-child and IE8 not supporting :last-child or :nth-child() and having to add classes like "first", "last", etc to style specific elements in those browsers as a result. Now that pretty much every browser version that's still relevant today supports these features... no one wants to use them anymore.

Comment: I think we're thinking on different scales here. Yes, for self-explanatory things like "first in a list", `:first-child` is great. I was thinking of more distant elements like `header .date-widget` and `.sidebar .date-widget` or such.

Comment: That I agree. I also tend to place more emphasis on keeping the markup semantically meaningful and designing the CSS around it, only adding affordances where absolutely necessary. By the way I think the idea of decoupling CSS from HTML is a little strange (although *loosely* coupling is another thing). Everyone writes HTML differently - it's pretty much impossible to design a single stylesheet that can be used to style a variety of documents written by different people or programs. Yet some people out there seem to believe otherwise.

Comment: Certainly, it's virtually impossible to write a stylesheet which is equally applicable to any HTML. That's basically what Bootstrap and co do, and you'll end up writing HTML to the stylesheet, which isn't really great either. The sanest thing really is [custom web components](http://webcomponents.org), tying HTML and CSS into a self-contained bundle. Without going quite that far, you can somewhat emulate that with classes and the awareness of keeping logical elements self-contained.

Comment: In the end it's just *naming things*, [how hard can that possibly be](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)?! :o)